# how to rearrange my if statement so I don't duplicate the result in my outfile

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am testing for a key, and if it is present, am doing a json.dump, and if not present, am adding it. I'm also checking for two other keys and if they are not present, adding them. I nested those secondary tests.

With this code, it works fine if the key is present, but if not, when it adds it, it additionally adds the json.dump when it shouldn't. Should this be two different functions? Or how can I rearrange it so it stops after it adds the key?

```
import json

def extract_metadata(input_filename, output_filename, wanted_key):

    with open(input_filename, "r") as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)

    with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:

        if "extended" in data['metadata']:
            if "key_1" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
                data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_1={})
            else:
                pass    
            if "key_2" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
                data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_2={})
            else:
                pass        

        json.dump(data["metadata"], outfile)


        else: 
            data['metadata'].update(extended={"loadedBy": "company"})

            json.dump(data['metadata'], outfile)
```

*******improved working code********

```
    if "extended" in data['metadata']:
        if "key_1" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
        data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_1={})

        if "key_2" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
        data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_2={})
        with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(data['metadata'], outfile)        

else: 
    data['metadata'].update(extended={"loadedBy": "company"})
    changed = True

if changed == True:
    with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data['metadata'], outfile)
```

Comment: Why doesn't the function use `wanted_key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable that indicates whether you made any changes to the data. If the variable isn't true, don't dump to the output file.

```
def extract_metadata(input_filename, output_filename, wanted_key):

    with open(input_filename, "r") as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)

    changed = False

    if "extended" in data['metadata']:
        if "key_1" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
            data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_1={})
            changed = True
        if "key_2" not in data['metadata']['extended']:
            data['metadata']['extended'].update(key_2={})
            changed = True    
    else: 
        data['metadata'].update(extended={"loadedBy": "company"})
        changed = True

    if changed:
        with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(data['metadata'], outfile)
```

BTW, you don't need `else: pass`, you can simply leave out the `else:` clause.

Comment: Remember, if this helped you, you can accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot--the Boolean was totally the solution. I modified the code a bit and put that in the original question. If the "extended" key were present, I didn't want the dump to be dependent on the other keys, so I altered that part.